# VLookup for two values IN Excel TABLE

Tags: excel

I need a formula for the below table to look up 2 values if it matches I should get the desired information. I tried the following formula but not working   =VLOOKUP(D2 & C5,A2:D5,2,FALSE)

result sohlud be = 300

for example

looking values are USER & OID if matched, should give the AMOUNT value

[image]

Comment: Instead of `VLOOKUP()` try using `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` with a delimiter in between for the lookup value or use `XLOOKUP()`.

Comment: Why don't you share the rest of the information (a screenshot or an explanation)? I  mean, you have to read the values from somewhere to look them up in this table and return the result (somewhere). You should use structured references to reap the benefits of the data being in an Excel table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use FILTER: [filter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) instead:

```
=FILTER(B2:B5,(C2:C5=C5)*(D2:D5=D2))
```

Result:

[image]